# Using CSS selectors to set style

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML that looks like the following:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <div class="some-group open">
    <ul class="multi-item-container some-list">
      <li class="multi-item multi-group multi-group-button">
        <label>Header text</label>
      </li>
      <li><a ...>...</a></li>
      <li><a ...>...</a></li>
      <li><a ...>...</a></li>
      <li class="multi-item multi-group multi-group-button">
        <label>Another header</label>
      </li>
      <li><a ...>...</a></li>
      <li><a ...>...</a></li>
      <li><a ...>...</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know I want the `label` elements that represent headers to use the following CSS:

```
... {
  padding-left:0px;
  margin-left:-24px;
}
```

However, I do not know how to use a nested CSS selector that starts at `myDiv`. How do I use a CSS selector to update my headers with this style?

THanks!

Comment: `#myDiv li label { }` Labels are for `inputs` though, not for `lists`. [Read more about labels here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, and it can depend on a variety of factors, but these would work:

Less specific:

```
#myDiv label {...}
```

More specific:

```
#myDiv div.some-group.open ul.multi-item-container.some-list li.multi-item.multi-group.multi-group-button label {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply 'walk' down the DOM from `#myDiv` to `label`

```
#myDiv ul li label
```